# Rx.Observable interval example for a string variable

Tags: typescript, angular, rxjs

I'm completely new to Angular2 and TypeScript. I'm currently trying to implement an Rx.Observable call every 2 seconds for a string variable. I've implemented a similar function before but for a string array (code below):

```
    return Rx.Observable
        .interval(2000)
        .flatMap(() => this._http.get(url))
        .map((trainingStatus: Array<string>) => {
            let result: Array<string> = [];
            if (trainingStatus) {
                trainingStatus.forEach((msg) => {
                    msg.timeStampDate = new Date(msg.timeStamp);
                    result.push(msg);
                });
            }
            console.log(result);
            return result;
        });
```

Could someone explain how to do the same thing but for a string variable? I've tried changing 'Array' to simply 'string', but the 'forEach' throws an error.

**EDIT:
Found a solution:**

```
    return Rx.Observable
        .interval(2000)
        .flatMap(() => this._http.get(url))
        .map(<Response>(response) => { return response.text() });
```

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: Property 'foreach' does not exist on type 'string'.

Comment: That's because forEach is only applicable to array structures. You can't iterate over a string.

Comment: Could you explain what this part of the code is doing? => this._http.get(url)

Comment: That is a REST GET call that would return a string.

Comment: Found a solution - see original post.

Comment: @Roka545 Move your solution to an answer so it can be selected/upvoted.